# How to show a view inside a view node.js

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a view, route and controller for my dashboard. I also have a route, view and controller for widgets. On the dashboard I want to show those widgets. If I go to [localhost:3000/widget](http://localhost:3000/widget) I can actually see the data pulling from the database and it's all working. But, on my dashboard view if I try to include it like:

```
<%- include('../widget/widget.ejs') %>
```

Then no data shows up whatsoever and I don't see any error in console. What is the correct way to do this?

Here is the widget route:

```
router.get('/widget', isAuth, widgetController.getIndex);
```

Widget controller:

```
const Product = require("../models/product");

exports.getIndex = (req, res, next) => {
 Product.find({ "requests.userId": req.user }, {title: 1})
    .then(product => {
      res.render("widget/widget", {
        path: "/widget",
        product: product
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

The widget view:

```
            <% for (const products of product) { %>
            <li><i class="list-box-icon sl sl-icon-doc"></i>
                <strong><%= products.title %></strong>
            </li>
            <% } %>
```

Dashboard route:

```
router.get('/dashboard', accountController.getDashboard);
```

The dashboard controller is quite a lot of code so I have just reduced it to its simplest form.

```
exports.getDashboard = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.user._id == '5d57abbd24e21t41u56c1t66') {
    Product.find({ status: "pending" })
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .then(products => {
      res.render("account/dashboard", {
        pageTitle: "Dashboard",
        path: "/dashboard",
        products: products
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      const error = new Error(err);
      error.httpStatusCode = 500;
      return next(error);
    });
```

Comment: If the `widget` view pulls some data from the database, then you can make an ajax request instead of a normal http request. Then you can include the EJS view with it's script (where the ajax request is done).

Comment: Can you show the code for where /widget is served and also where your dashboard is served?

Comment: @Paul, not sure if I have given you what you were looking for now, but please let me know if not (I edited the original question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so the issue you're seeing is that in the widget route, you pull the data from the database and then render that to the component ejs.  In the dashboard view, the `include` directive just renders the HTML from the ejs template, there's no data to fill in.

Your options are several.  The easiest (though maybe not most efficient) might be to just do the same DB query in the dashboard, then include the relevant data in the local object you are sending to the view.

Another common approach, as mentioned in the comments, would be to have a clientside request via ajax that calls the widget endpoint and injects the result in the dashboard at the appropriate spot.

The first approach makes it easier to render the dashboard all at once, while the second is a better approach for progressive loading of widgets and separation of data queries.